# Beta managed package cannot be installed. Error: Package Not Found

Tags: managed-package

The newly created packages which are created on 15/08/2016 cannot be installed in other dev orgs after waiting for almost 24 hours.

The error is :
Package Not Found
The requested package does not exist or has been deleted. Please contact the package publisher for assistance. If this is a recently uploaded package, please try again soon.

The org where the packages were created is on NA9. The orgs where the packages were installed are on AP1 and AP2.

But the packages were created before 15/08 are still working.

Comment: You will have to raise a case with support for this .

Comment: I tried, but for standard customers, cannot raise a case for development packaging and only can ask in community...

Comment: If you are a partner post in technical enablement with your case number to get it escalated. Other than that SF is the only one who can help. Welcome to the catch 22. Ensure you are copying the link correctly. In fact click on it and log into the destination org that way.

Answer (score 1):

After waiting for two days, those packages can be installed now.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using Salesforce support, creating a new package version (with no changes) would probably be the fastest way to get your package deployed.